# Flutter Web App does not load without subdomain on Firebase

Tags: dns, firebase-hosting

I try to deploy my web app written in Flutter on Firebase.

The problem:

It does not show up after deployment if I do not add a subdomain.

For example:

> www.website.com
>   test.website.com
>   xyz.website.com
>   anything.website.com

... works greatly!

While only 'website.com' fails to work.

Any ideas?